# How to plot 3 different time-series with "actual" values rather than a density plot as ridgeline plots (formerly known as Joyplots) in R?

Tags: r

I would like to plot ridgeline plots of 3 different timeseries with same axes with actual values, but NOT a density plot as ridgeplots generally show.

Tried using Henrik Lindberg's code here : https://github.com/halhen/viz-pub/tree/master/sports-time-of-day

It does what it is supposed to do, but can not produce smoothing.
Also tried the ggridges manual codes (below)

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = time, y = activity, height = p)) + geom_density_ridges()
```

ggridges produces density plots, not as a timeseries as I want it to be. Henrik's code produces desired timeseries, but without the smoothing as I wanted from a ridgeplot.